# Elastic Package in R : Error: 404 - IndexMissingException[[epgs_20%2A] missing]

Tags: r

When I run this command in RStudio,

```
library(elastic)

connect("192.12.32.2")
```

The following message/output comes:

> Found http or https on es_host, stripping off, see the docs
>
> transport:  http
>
> host:       192.12.32.2
>
> port:       9200
>
> path:       NULL
>
> username:   NULL
>
> password:   [secret]
>
> errors:     simple
>
> headers (names):  NULL

After this I ran this command,

```
res <- Search(index = 'epgs_20*', fields = c("ts", "ma", "pi", "tn", "Ope"),scroll="5m",search_type = "scan")
```

and I get the following error:

> Error: 404 - IndexMissingException[[epgs_20%2A] missing].

If instead of above index = 'epgs_20*', we use index = 'epgs_2016.2.07'. It works fine but when using * it doesn't work. 
How do I run the above command with index = 'epgs_20*' ?

Comment: [Solved] Created an alias for the index value and searched using the alias name.

Comment: Please make an effort to format your questions here, thanks. I've trimmed off the [solved] as we don't do that - please add an answer instead.